# Converting MSSQL stored procedures to MySQL - CONCAT issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server, syntax

I have a question regarding the conversion of MSSQL stored procedures to MySQL ones.

I used http://www.sqlines.com/online to convert my MSSQL file to a MySQL syntactically valid format. There was an issue converting the following to MySQL:

```
set @InspectionNo =  right('0' + convert(varchar(10),@i),2)
```

The converted output showed:

```
set v_InspectionNo =  right(Concat('0' , convert(varchar(10),@i)),2)
```

which doesn't appear to be the correct syntax.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated, it's got me stumped!

Comment: Also without seeing the stored procedures codes we also can't suggest something more solid also keep in mind that MySQL might not support some native SQL Server (MSSQL) features like DOMAINS

Comment: Can I use nchar instead of varchar? @RaymondNijland

Comment: *"Can I use nchar instead of varchar?"*  Stackoverflow is not meant into not having to research dig yourself in the manual -> but *"ANSI/ISO Standard SQL defines NCHAR or NATIONAL CHAR as a way to indicate that a CHAR column should use some predefined character set. MySQL uses utf8 as this predefined character set"* which MySQL 5.5+ does [support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-national.html)

Comment: But keep in mind that SQL Server (MSSQL) internally stores [NCHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as UTF 16 or as UCS-2 so keep that in mind when testing.. As utf16 does allow storing much more that utf8 would for example..  So you might want to define `VARCHAR(<number>) CHARACTER SET utf16/ucs2` in MySQL instead of using `NCHAR`

Comment: thank @RaymondNijland

Comment: no problem, but with all respect stackoverflow is not really meant into to not having to research dig yourself in the manuals to find differences between RDMS

Comment: @RaymondNijland I appreciate what you're saying, however I have spent quite some time researching this on multiple different sites and couldn't find a solution. I only used stackoverflow as a last resort, hoping that somebody could explain it to me so I understand, instead of just copying from google. Clearly I was mistaken.

Comment: seams i was also unclear with that comment, i mostly meant the comment *"Can I use nchar instead of varchar?"*  with mine comment .. Anyhow a cross vendor RDMS migrations are complex as every vendor is using a SQL dialect based on a SQL standard so you might not always find a "one on one" solution..  It is clear you did some research as sqllines has some resources on how to convert some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to the following. In mysql, you cannot cast to varchar, only char is supported.

```
set v_InspectionNo =  right(Concat('0' , cast(@i AS char(10))),2)
```